# XLSB Personal Macro file Variable Error

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, xlsm, xlsb

Disclaimer: This is not my code. I took a macro from a regular xlsm file and placed it on a xslb file to have it handy for analysis. The macro works correctly in the xlsm, but encounters a variable issue on the xlsb file.

`ColumnToFormat` identifies a specific column. I verified that the column is present within the worksheet on my Locals window.

[image]

Main Sub

```
ColumnToFormat = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("OR_TR_OLD_BAL", ActiveSheet.Rows(1), False)

Call FormatAmounts
```

When I start running `FormatAmounts`, however, the variable disappears and Excel throws a RunTime Error 1004; Application Defined or Object Defined Error. When testing the xlsm file, this does not happen. The variable gets passed from the main sub to the helper sub. See `FormatAmounts` sub below.

[image]

```
Sub FormatAmounts()
ActiveSheet.Columns(ColumnToFormat).Select
 Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range(ActiveSheet.Columns(ColumnToFormat).Address), DataType:= _
        xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlNone, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
        Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:= _
        False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Selection.NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is ColumnToFormat defined?

Comment: Wow, I totally missed it. It's a Public ColumnToFormat as Integer. I must have missed when copying and pasting since there are a few modules in the original spreadsheet. Seems to be working as it was before. Thank you so much!

Comment: Option Explicit fixes issues like this before they start.  Just saying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the ColumnToFormat value over to the sub procedure and add error control in the main sub by using Application.Match to a variant and testing the variant for error.

```
sub main()
    dim ColumnToFormat  as variant

    ColumnToFormat = Application.Match("OR_TR_OLD_BAL", ActiveSheet.Rows(1), 0)

    if not iserror(ColumnToFormat ) then FormatAmounts clng(ColumnToFormat)
end sub

Sub FormatAmounts(c as long)
    with ActiveSheet.Columns(c)
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.cells(1), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlNone, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
                       Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, _
                       FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        .NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    end with
End Sub
```